# AirPlay video with audio on iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, airplay

Is it possible to send video through AirPlay and have the audio on the iOS device?

I want to watch a movie on the Apple TV but have the audio in my EarPods connected to my iPhone.

The Apple TV can send audio through AirPlay but I can't find an app for iOS that can receive audio without jailbreak.

Answer (score 1):

That is currently not possible.

You can make it a feature request to Apple

here

http://www.apple.com/feedback/appletv.html

or here

http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

You can come up with your description but here is a draft:

*

> Feature request: I'd love it you could activate "private listening"
>   with Apple TV. Pop headphones into your iPhone or iPad and listen to
>   the audio from the Apple TV it's connected to without bothering other
>   people in your living space.

*